# How to get notified if a USB device of a specific interface is connected in Windows?

Tags: android, .net, windows, usb, winusb

I would like to be informed, if a (Android) USB device of a specific interface (USB debugging) is connected to my Windows computer.

For this, I'm trying to use .Net with this code:

```
const string GUID_DEVINTERFACE_ANDROID = "f72fe0d4-cbcb-407d-8814-9ed673d0dd6b";
const string usbDeviceSelector = "System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{" + GUID_DEVINTERFACE_ANDROID + "}\" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True";

_usbDeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
    usbDeviceSelector,
    new string[] { "System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled" },
    DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
_usbDeviceWatcher.Updated += UsbDeviceWatcher_Updated;
```

Unfortunately, the event will not be thrown to my `UsbDeviceWatcher_Update` function.

I don't want to be informed about a specific device, I want to be notified about all devices, which supports this interface.

**How can I get an event, if an device with this special interface will be connected / disconnected from my computer?**

If there is a `WinUsb` solution for this, I would be happy too.

Comment: You can run "adb devices" command. It will list all available debug-able android devices currently connected to the computer. You can run this command in a thread once every X seconds or so

Comment: Have you tried `_usbDeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(new Guid("f72fe0d4-cbcb-407d-8814-9ed673d0dd6b")));`?

Comment: @Codo: Unfortunately, this doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter for the a USB device with the interface class `{f72fe0d4-cbcb-407d-8814-9ed673d0dd6b}` and then subscribe to the `Added` and `Removed` events:

```
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.Usb;

var filter = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(new Guid("f72fe0d4-cbcb-407d-8814-9ed673d0dd6b"));
var usbDeviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(filter);
usbDeviceWatcher.Added += UsbDeviceWatcher_Added;
usbDeviceWatcher.Removed += UsbDeviceWatcher_Removed;
usbDeviceWatcher.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Press key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();

void UsbDeviceWatcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Added");
}

void UsbDeviceWatcher_Removed(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Removed");
}
```

Alternatively, you can also filter for interface class 0xff, subclass 0x42 and protocol 0x01:

```
var filter = UsbDevice.GetDeviceClassSelector(new UsbDeviceClass() {
    ClassCode = 0xff,
    SubclassCode = 0x42,
    ProtocolCode = 0x01
});
```

You can also implement the approach proposed by David Grayson's. But it's considerably more effort.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to get notified of new or removed USB devices in Windows is to listen for the WM_DEVICECHANGE message sent by the OS to your window.  This will give you more notifications than you care about, so whenever you get that message, you should use your favorite library or program to list the devices you care about and see if anything changed.

You will need to override your windows `WndProc` message.  The documentation here discusses how to do that in C#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?view=windowsdesktop-7.0